# Can rsync detrimentally affect the performance of the source server?

Tags: rsync

I'm planning to run an `rsync` command on Server A, to copy 40GB of files to Server B.

Server A is a production server, Server B is not.

If I run rsync on Server A, can the command detrimentally affect the performance of that server? It needs to continue to work as an FTP server during the transfer.

Comment: Run with highest nice and ionice.

Comment: In short yes of course it can have an impact on the performance of both the source and destination. See for instance [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/q/381488/37681) for mitigating measures.

Comment: For fun, try rsyncing to a USB stick mounted on your workstation, and watch the rest of the system crawwwwllllll.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure, `rsync` is gonna take all the possible bandwitch to transfer the data but you can always use the option `--bwlimit` like so:

`rsync --bwlimit=5000 /foo user@serverB:/bar`

This will limit transfering speed to 5Mb/s

Or you can also use [ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) as already pointed out.

Comment: I will use it in conjunction with ionice as described in the [Q&A](http://serverfault.com/q/381488/37681) linked above, the usage looks straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

"Can rsync detrimentally affect the performance of the source server?"

Yes, of course, any new load can detrimentally affect the performance of a server - but you've not let us know the spec or utilisation of the source or target servers, their NICs or the bandwidth, latency and utilisation of the links between them - so we can't answer this with any degree of certainty.